# Where is related product place in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, related-products

In product view xml , i found that

```
<referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

How is the html called from template?

Comment: Have you helpful below answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html file is called from Catalog module.

```
magento2.1/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

**Related, Upsell and cross sell product display inside detail page are coming from here.**

Here in top file, `$type = $block->getType()` getting value of related, upsell,crosssell and based on value dynamic content are loaded in specific block.

Comment: How can we get  customtype  products in items.phtml along with Related, Upsell and cross sell products